# Problems releasing components since REDHAWK 2.1.0

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using REDHAWK 2.1.0 on CentOS 7, and running components in the Python Sandbox with ossie.utils.sb.

Sometimes when I call "component.releaseObject()" it just hangs. The C++ implementation of releaseObject is actually never called. This was not encountered in previous REDHAWK versions.

The setup is an rh.SigGen connected to some component. The problem seems to occur only when "sri_blocking" is set to True on the SigGen, and when the connected component is spending more time in the serviceFunction().

I do not get the same problem when rh.FileReader is the source instead. I am curious if this is related to FileReader ending the stream when the component stops. SigGen does not end the current stream.

I created a test_component, with a single property, "delay". Its serviceFunction() looks like:

```
bulkio::InFloatPort::dataTransfer *pkt = dataFloat_in->getPacket(bulkio::Const::NON_BLOCKING);

if (not pkt) {
    return NOOP;
}

if (pkt->sriChanged) {
    dataFloat_out->pushSRI(pkt->SRI);
}

if (pkt->inputQueueFlushed) {
    LOG_WARN(test_component_i, "INPUT QUEUE FLUSHED!");
}

usleep(delay);

dataFloat_out->pushPacket(&pkt->dataBuffer[0], pkt->dataBuffer.size(), pkt->T, pkt->EOS, pkt->streamID);

delete pkt;
return NORMAL;
```

Delay is used to simulate a length of time for processing. In my case 100 usec delay resulted in a clean exit of the script below when using the SigGen as the source. However, 1000 usec resulted in a hang on the first "releaseObject()" call:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ossie.utils import sb
import numpy as np


def setupSigGen():
    c = sb.launch('rh.SigGen')
    c.sri_blocking = True
    c.throttle = False
    c.xfer_len = 10000
    return c, 'dataFloat_out'


def setupFileReader():
    np.array(range(10000), dtype=np.float).tofile('/tmp/fileReaderInput.32f')
    c = sb.launch('rh.FileReader')
    c.advanced_properties.throttle_rate = '-1'
    c.advanced_properties.ignore_header_metadata = True
    c.advanced_properties.looping = True
    c.sample_rate = '1Gsps'
    c.file_format = 'FLOAT'
    c.source_uri = 'file:///tmp/fileReaderInput.32f'
    return c, 'dataFloat_out'


def startSigGen(c):
    c.start()


def startFileReader(c):
    c.start()
    c.playback_state = 'PLAY'


def setupComp(config=None):
    c = sb.launch('test_component')
    if config is not None:
        c.configure(config)
    return c, 'dataFloat_in'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '-f',
        '--use-file-reader',
        default = False,
        action = 'store_true')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-d',
        '--delay',
        type = int,
        default = 1000)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.use_file_reader == True:
        setupSource = setupFileReader
        startSource = startFileReader
        print 'Using rh.FileReader'
    else:
        setupSource = setupSigGen
        startSource = startSigGen
        print 'Using rh.SigGen'
    src, usesPortName = setupSource()
    comp, providesPortName = setupComp({'delay': args.delay})
    src.connect(comp,
                usesPortName=usesPortName,
                providesPortName=providesPortName)
    comp.start()
    startSource(src)
    raw_input('Enter any key to stop...')
    src.stop()
    comp.stop()
    src.releaseObject() # <--- hangs here when src is an rh.SigGen
    comp.releaseObject()
```

If I remove the "stop()" calls, and instead just use "releaseObject()", then the script also exits cleanly.

As far as implementing source components, does this mean that a source components should send end the stream on "stop()"? (Does "stop()" always mean STOP, or can it be a PAUSE?) The rh.FileReader uses the "playback_state" property to provide PAUSING. Is this a good practice to follow?

I have also tried this with a custom file source component as the source. Unless I send the end-of-stream on "stop()" then the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario as shown definitely locks up. The issue is that the input queue for test_component is full (and not being serviced) when the sandbox cleans up the components before release. As part of the cleanup, the sandbox disconnects the components. As part of the disconnect, the port base class sends a zero-length packet with EOS set to true to indicate that the stream is done; that call is locking up. Neither the component making the push nor the sandbox are timing out, leading to the locked state. This is a sandbox problem only, and should not be an issue with a running Domain.

In REDHAWK 2.1.0, I recommend setting a sleep after stopping the data source component. That should empty the queue (you just need one more empty slot), and the call associated with the disconnect can be serviced.

This problem was fixed in REDHAWK 2.1.1 (https://github.com/redhawksdr/redhawk/releases/tag/2.1.1)